# Why is there no float in VBA?

Tags: vba

More of a theoretical question, but is there any particular reason why there is no float data type (32 bit numeric with decimal sign) in the VBA programming language?

There doesn't seem to be any logical programming limitation in VBA and it is well capable of utilizing `Double` (64 bit). Is it just an oversight -- considering it to be unnecessary or is there a logical reason behind lack of float in VBA?

Comment: Single perhaps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/single-data-type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a `Single` data type available, not only for Visual Basic, but also for [Visual Basic for Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278621(v=office.14).aspx):

> `Single` (single-precision floating-point) variables are stored as IEEE 32-bit (4-byte) floating-point numbers, ranging in value from -3.402823E38 to -1.401298E-45 for negative values and from 1.401298E-45 to 3.402823E38 for positive values. The type-declaration character for `Single` is the exclamation point (`!`).